# Change the "Send Invite Invitation" text in fb:request-form tag

Tags: facebook, fbml

I need to change the text "Send Invite Invitation" that appear on the Button on fb:request-form tag in Facebook.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think there was an attribute

try

invite="true" OR invite="false" to see if it will change